# Rails send mail with GMail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, gmail, imap

I am on rails 2.3.5 and have the latest Ruby installed and my application is running well, except, GMail emails.

I am trying to setup my gmail imap connection which has worked previously but now doesnt want to know.

This is my code:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file

# Uncomment below to force Rails into production mode when
# you don't control web/app server and can't set it the proper way
# ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'

# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

# Bootstrap the Rails environment, frameworks, and default configuration
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')


Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  # Gems
  config.gem "capistrano-ext", :lib => "capistrano"
  config.gem "configatron"

  # Make Time.zone default to the specified zone, and make Active Record store time values
  # in the database in UTC, and return them converted to the specified local zone.
  config.time_zone = "London"

  # The internationalization framework can be changed to have another default locale (standard is :en) or more load paths.
  # All files from config/locales/*.rb,yml are added automatically.
  # config.i18n.load_path << Dir[File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}')]
  #config.i18n.default_locale = :de

  # Your secret key for verifying cookie session data integrity.
  # If you change this key, all old sessions will become invalid!
  # Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random, 
  # no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
  config.action_controller.session = {
    :session_key => '_base_session',
    :secret      => '7389ea9180b15f1495a5e73a69a893311f859ccff1ffd0fa2d7ea25fdf1fa324f280e6ba06e3e5ba612e71298d8fbe7f15fd7da2929c45a9c87fe226d2f77347'
  }

  config.active_record.observers = :user_observer

end

ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:default => '%d/%m/%Y')
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:default => '%d/%m/%Y')

require "will_paginate"

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "XXXXXXXX.XXX",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX.XXX",
  :password => "XXXXX"
}
```

But the above just results in an SMTP auth error in the production log.

I have read varied reports of this not working in Rails 2.2.2 but nothing for 2.3.5, anyone got any ideas?

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [action mailer optional tls](http://github.com/collectiveidea/action_mailer_optional_tls)