# Mail not actually being sent though my log says it is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

Rails 2.3.5

This is on my local.

I have a simple model / view/ controller

```
#contact.rb

def deliver_contact
  ContactMailer.deliver_contact(self)
end

#contacts_controller

def create
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

  respond_to do |wants|
    if @contact.save
      @contact.deliver_contact
      #flash[:notice] = 'Contact was successfully created.'
      wants.html { redirect_to('/thanks') }
    else
      wants.html { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
```

The log says its going out.. i can do it in my console and it says its going out. But nothing actually is received in my inbox. What am I missing?

**Update**

Here is my `development.rb`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => '25',
  :domain => "website.com",
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name => "snackmail@gmail.com",
  :password => "aged-cheese"
}
```

**The Create Log**

```
Processing ContactsController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-11-28 16:12:49) [POST]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"PUNCH IT, CHEWY!", "action"=>"create", "authenticity_token"=>"3zayXGIOWeNLwb+jhx5cIxWgHqEJdv6iwj6I=", "contact"=>{"name"=>"bob marley", "message"=>"asdfasdf", "state_id"=>"Regarding an existing order", "email"=>"daniel@gmail.com"}, "controller"=>"contacts"}
Cache miss: Spree::Config ({})
  Preference Load (0.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "preferences" WHERE ("preferences".owner_id = 1 AND "preferences".owner_type = 'Configuration') 
  Configuration Load (0.1ms)   SELECT * FROM "configurations" WHERE ("configurations"."id" = 1) 
  CACHE (0.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "configurations" WHERE ("configurations"."id" = 1) 
Cache write (will save 2.65ms): Spree::Config
  Contact Create (0.8ms)   INSERT INTO "contacts" ("name", "city", "zip", "created_at", "optin", "updated_at", "state_id", "message", "email") VALUES('bob marley', NULL, NULL, '2010-11-28 21:12:49', NULL, '2010-11-28 21:12:49', 'Regarding an existing order', 'asdfasdf', 'daniel.levine4@gmail.com')
Sent mail to daniel@gmail.com

Date: Sun, 28 Nov 2010 16:12:50 -0500
From: info@jersey.com
To: daniel@gmail.com
Subject: HOLY !@ you got mail!
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<strong>You have just received a dank crispy email.</strong>
<br />
<p>
  Here are the details of the message:
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  bob marley
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  daniel@gmail.com
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Subject:</strong>
  Regarding an existing order
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Message:</strong>
  <br />
  asdfasdf
</p>
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/thanks
Completed in 893ms (DB: 5) | 302 Found [http://localhost/contacts]
```

**update:**

Tried using the gmail tls plugin but it didn't work. tried moving the settings around to environment.rb to development.rb .

I am using spree, but if I put something in environment or development.rb in /config it overrides Spree's defaults. Alternatively, I can create the mail server from within Spree's admin, and with the right specs, it still doesn't budge.

Comment: Does mail-sending work at all on that machine?

Comment: Did you check your SPAM folder?

Comment: @martin, yes it does on my other applications. --- @bitxwise, yes I did, and nothing appeared there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two items that solved this piece for me.

1. I was using Spree, so that I meant I had to configure the mail settings internally. Before I realized that I had gone with @lbz's request to install a plugin for TLS in Gmail sendings. It turns out, that that silently conflicted with the settings, so when I uninstalled it, it worked.
2. To get emails to be sent on your testing server, you must also comment this line :

   `# config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test`

Answer (score 6):

If you are running your application in develop mode your email will not be sent but logged. To actually send an email in develop mode change `config/environment.rb` to something like:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  ...
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail # add this line
end
```

Comment: Also make sure sendmail is configured properly on your system.

Comment: Can you please add the log about the `create` action?

Comment: If you are going to send via Gmail please install this https://github.com/collectiveidea/action_mailer_optional_tls and have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783811/rails-send-mail-with-gmail

Comment: @lbz, hmm, i installed the plugin, and tried the smtp settings it provided to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

In `config\environments\development.rb` do you still have the following lines:

```
# Don't care if the mailer can't send
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

If so, comment those, and add the following lines
to enable deliveries from development:

```
# To test if we can actually send mails!
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true # for test
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. seems like no errors come out though when i perform `deliver_contact` in console.